DRQN with LSTM, abnormal Q-values
I'm implementing Deep Recurrent Q-learning mentioned in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.06527 with sequential update.
To verify my implementation is correct, I plotted the following:
1.test return over training episodes (1 test every 1000 training episodes)
2.Q-values of all actions at first time step (1st time step Q should converge to optimal return)
3.selected action's Q vs observed return (it should look like a y = x function)
The result look like this(labels and legends of plot might be incorrect):
return converged to around 85 which is the optimal return

first time step Q-value

selected action's Q vs observed return for a test episode(5 time steps so 5 data points)

The Q-values seem abnormal as they rise to values much higher than the maximum return, then suddenly drop to values that are close to maximum return. I also plotted the same metrics for DQN, and the Q-values were smooth and accurate.
I suspect that the LSTM hidden state input might be affecting the output, but I have no experience with LSTMs and not sure if this behavior is common.
Can anyone offer any suggestions?
